# Determining what year a product launches based on an array of sales in geographies

Tags: excel, reference

I'm trying to put together a formula that returns a year when a product launches in a particular geography. The relevant data array is on another tab, and contains the information attached in the following link. [Sales Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR9EB.png)

I was thinking along the lines of trying to compare two cells, so that in the US, between B3 and C3 there is a value change from zero to positive, at which point, the formula would return the year 2020. Or similarly, in Europe, between B4 and C4 there would be no difference, but between C4 and D4, product launch occurs, so the formula would return 2021.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to achieve a solution is to use the following formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$I$2;1;COUNTIF(B3:I3;"=0")+1)
```

The Formula return 2020 for US, if you copy it down it should give you the results for the other rows.

The `INDEX` Formula returns a value based on a matrix `$B$2:$I$2`, a row `1` and a column input number. This number is the amount of zeros plus one. Unfortunately, this works only, if all data points in the future are non-zero. Maybe someone else can build up on this.